# MYSQL UPDATE query using ORDER BY and LIMIT on a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a UPDATE query which will SUM the `rewards_balance` of only 5 users sorted by the date of their purchase.

`Users` table is :

```
id     rewards_balance
1      0
2      20
3      0
4      23
5      11
6      45
7      1
8      0
9      0 
10     10
```

Here is my `subscription` table

```
payer_id     created
1           1616137161
2           1616137165
5           1616137166
7           1616137167
3           1616137168
4           1616137169
9           1616137175
```

The UPDATE query should work in such a way that it will add a set amount to 5 users who have had the subscription first. So the output after UPDATE should be as follows

```
id     rewards_balance
1      0+20
2      20+20
3      0+20
4      23
5      11+20
6      45
7      1+20
8      0
9      0 
10     10
```

So as you see, the 20 is added to only those IDs who have their subscription first.

What I have tried so far is :

```
UPDATE users u LEFT JOIN subscription m ON u.id = m.payer_id SET u.rewards_balance = u.rewards_balance+20
ORDER BY `m`.`created` ASC LIMIT 10
```

I keep getting the following error.

`Query error: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`

Assist please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are not allowed in multi-table UPDATE. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

You can do this instead:

```
UPDATE users u 
JOIN (
  SELECT m.payer_id
  FROM subscription m
  ORDER BY `m`.`created`
  LIMIT 10
) q on q.payer_id=u.id
SET u.rewards_balance = u.rewards_balance+20;
```

Comment: I realized that. However what could be the work around anyway? I think the solution should be simple. But I'm just doing it in wrong way.

Comment: @YaseenHussain It is quite simple. Use a derived table instead.